# Cannot access WHM and SSH/root after a configuration in Host Access Control

Tags: cpanel, ip-address, linux, whm

I added my IP (like 172.32.1.0/255.255.255.0) to allow access for `ssh`, `whm` and `cpanel` in WHM -> Host Access Control. Then, I added all IP to deny access for them. However, after saved changes, I lost access all of them. Now, If I try to login WHM, I see that:

> **HTTP error 401**
>
> You do not have permission to access this page.

Also, I cannot access SSH. I don't know what to do. If I restart server, will the problem be solved?

Comment: Would help if you show us the file you used to allow and disallow. Furthermore I do not recommend using IP deny, using secure SSH keys is the preferred method and extremely secure.

Comment: Assuming that you saved your changes a restart wouldn't clear your IP blocks. How would you restart the server anyways? Do you have access to IPMI? If so you could SSH in that way; otherwise contact your host.

Comment: @SimonHayter You right, I should've used preferred keys but I want to hide Cpanel and WHM login for others. So, I did not use a file. I adjusted to allow and deny from Host Access Control Page in WHM panel.

Comment: @Analog I don't have permission for SSH due to blocking Ip. I can only restart or rebuild my server in the panel of my server provider.

Comment: I meant accessing the console over IPMI since all external access is blocked. If there is no live traffic being hosted on that server you could try restarting it but cPanel *should* be saving the Host access rules through restarts. I'd just recommend contacting the host since they might be able to access the server over IPMI or directly from the DC and revert your changes.